# Apache Cordova: config.xml could not be found

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I'm using Apache Cordova in Visual Studio 2015.I'm new to it. I'm trying to make helloworld app .After the build is successfull, I tried to debug using Android:Nexus Galaxy .It opens the chrome browser.It says that device is ready but on the right hand side it says:  config.xml could not be found in the applications root or is malfunctioned XML.Consider me a novice and guide accordingly.Thank u

Comment: Cant judge the problem unless you show up your config.xml. It could be corrupted probably

Comment: I'm trying to make a simple app which displays helloworld just for begin the learning .What changes,etc do I need to do in config .xml

Comment: Install cordova CLI and execute cordova create project_name Your hello world project sis ready. Checjk out this link - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Comment: I have apache cordova in visual studio ..Can I get cordova terminal from visual studio ..I'm using windows

Comment: Actually I'm following some tutorials on creating helloworld app by using apache cordova in visual studio .... so can I resolve config.xml issues from  visual studio itself

Comment: you could but you gotta share your config.xml to see what exactly is the issue

Comment: Do you want to see the config.xml code or something else...I opened that file and it has some big code ....how should I share with you ?? I'm trying to copy here but its too long

Comment: You can edit your question and post it as part of it

Comment: Where is your config.xml file located? It needs to be at the root of your project, in the same directory as the www, platforms and plugins directories.

Comment: config.xml is at the root of my project